# Query Condition if nothing add 0

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I have a Laravel 5.7 query

```
$captains = DB::table('pickup_results')
    ->select(DB::raw("playerID"),
        DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Win'  THEN 1 END) AS wins"),
        DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Loss' THEN 1 END) AS loss"))
    ->where('pickOrder', '=', 0)
    ->where('playerID', '=', $playerID)
    ->groupBy('playerID')
    ->orderBy('wins','DESC')
    ->get();
```

If the playerID doesn't have a "Win" or a "Loss" it wont add the key of `wins` or `loss` to the query results -- thus resulting in errors when a user has no wins or no loss's in the database.

I Would like to be able to default `wins` or `loss` to `0` when a value doesn't exist in the database.

Can someone help me understand how I would achieve?

Comment: Do you have an Eloquent model set up for `pickup_results` and if so do you have a relationship set up between it and a `Player` model?

Comment: Are there any rows in the table for them at all if they haven't had a win or a loss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there isn't going to be a row in the table if the player hasn't had a win or a loss then your query isn't ever going to return any results.

One option (assuming you have a `players` table) would be to query the `players` table and then left join the `pickup_results`:

```
$captains = DB::table('players')
        ->leftJoin('pickup_results', 'players.id', 'pickup_results.playerID')
        ->select('users.id as user_id',
            DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN results.gameResult = 'Win'  THEN 1 END) AS wins"),
            DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN results.gameResult = 'Lose' THEN 1 END) AS loss"))
        ->where('players.id', $playerID)
        ->where('pickup_results.pickOrder', 0)
        ->groupBy('players.id')
        ->orderBy('wins', 'DESC')
        ->get();
```

Alternatively, since you're using `get()` with your query a collection will be returned regardless of any results so you could chain on the [whenEmpty()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-whenempty) method instead:

```
$captains = DB::table('pickup_results')
    ->select('playerID',
        DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Win'  THEN 1 END) AS wins"),
        DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Loss' THEN 1 END) AS loss"))
    ->where('pickOrder', 0)
    ->where('playerID', $playerID)
    ->groupBy('playerID')
    ->orderBy('wins', 'DESC')
    ->get()
    ->whenEmpty(function ($items) use ($playerID) {
        return $items->push((object)[
            'playerID' => $playerID,
            'wins'     => 0,
            'loss'     => 0,
        ]);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It will give you `wins` and `loss` in your result. Just add an `else` condition in your `case` and put an extra count condition for `draw` as well. Add more than 1 `orderBy` for better representation of results.

```
$captains = DB::table('pickup_results')
    ->select(DB::raw("playerID"),
        DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Win'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS wins"),
        DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Loss' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS loss")),
       DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN gameResult != 'Win' and gameResult != 'Loss' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS draws"))
    ->where('pickOrder', '=', 0)
    ->where('playerID', '=', $playerID)
    ->groupBy('playerID')
    ->orderBy('wins','DESC')
    ->orderBy('draws','DESC')
    ->orderBy('loss','ASC')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()` and add an `ELSE 0` to the query. Example for the first occurance:

```
DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Win' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS wins")
```

Or you can use `COALESCE(query, 0)`:

```
DB::raw("COALESCE(COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Win' THEN 1 END), 0) AS wins")
```

This works because `COUNT()` returns `NULL` if all counted elements are `NULL`.

Comment: What is the error you get? And what database system are you using by the way? MySql?